# IIS Slow response on POST requests

Tags: .net, iis, post, performance

We've got a .NET application as a front end with a Java based ECM solution as a back end. So the front-end does requests to the back-end through IIS.

The issue is that it works fine for GET requests, but POST requests are most of the times really slow (not always).

We've tried doing POST requests using the POSTER plugin for Firefox and it works fine (it takes less than a second per request) while the .NET app takes sometimes more than 20 seconds. I have to say that we've debugged the .NET app, and it doesn't seem to be anything in it, so this leads me to suspect IIS.

Comment: if you suspect it is iis, your question is better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: Any answers to this one yet? Experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Can you add logging into your application and check request and response time.. If its taking too much time in front end then you can further analyze by time taking for each method's entry and exit.

Comment: How big is the payload of the POST request? If it's a massive amount of data, your .NET application may be buffering until the entire request is in memory before it POSTs it to the ECM backend, which could introduce a lot of latency in addition to the memory utilization caused by buffering the POSTed data as it uploads from the browser.

Try using HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream(), and pass that stream to whatever API you use to post it to your Java backend.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195568.aspx

Comment: Does the same data works fast for a GET request ? How many worker processes are used in IIS ? What is the version of IIS ? Are you using classic or integrated pipeline of IIS ? Is your .net app is a service or Web forms or MVC application ?

Answer (score -1):

IIS has one of the best caching and compression systems to boost website. I run one myself and runs a like charm.

1. Enable compressio in iis.
2. Install wincache - make sure you install the latest version
3. Make sure you are running a non-threaded version of php 5
4. On iis manager enable output caching.

Comment: The question does not mention WordPress.